# How can I filter every query on a model with a certain condition in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter

I have a model that needs to have an attribute added to it to tell whether it is live or not, for example a boolean called disabled that can be set to true. I have a large codebase already and I don't want to add in an `unless disabled == false` condition to every query.

Is there some sort of before filter that I can run before every query to check this attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ActiveRecord default_scope statement. It will concatenate the scope you define to each query done through the model.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:disabled => false)
end
```

now running this:

```
MyModel.all
```

generates:

```
# => SELECT * FROM my_models WHERE disabled =false
```

The full documentation for it can be found [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope). I also made a [post about the topic](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/activerecord-default_scope/) in my blog. There are some nice insights about default_scope I'd recommend going through before applying it.